# Custom event bind not running $digest correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this fiddle for an easy example - http://jsfiddle.net/E7crq/4/

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope) {
        $scope.selectOption = 1;
});

app.directive('selectableOption', function () {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
             $(element[0]).on('myChange', function() {
                 scope.$digest();                 
             });             
             $(element[0]).on('change', function() {
                 scope.$digest();
             });
         }
    };
});

$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('#mainSelect option[value=' + $(this).attr('data-value') + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    $('#mainSelect').trigger('change');
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <select ng-model="selectOption" id="mainSelect" selectable-option>
            <option value="1">1</option>    
            <option value="2">2</option>    
            <option value="3">3</option>    
        </select>
        <div>
          Option: {{ selectOption }}
        <div>
            <button data-value="1" id="btn1">1</button>
            <button data-value="2" id="btn2">2</button>
            <button data-value="3" id="btn3">3</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The way it is currently written, if you click on any of the `1`, `2`, `3` buttons, it updates the scope and the selected value. If you change the event triggered by the last line of code from `'change'` to `'myChange'`, it doesn't work anymore.

I guess that's because Angular already has a handler for the `change` event. What do I need to do to make the `myChange` event to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't agree with this line of solution at all, as you are involving both jQuery outside of Angular in order to do Angular things.

First of all - you can do everything that you wanted in the $scope of the `controller`. Second - you can solve this inside the directive as well - but *please* use Angular syntax if you are going to be coding in Angular.

I've changed the jsFiddle in http://jsfiddle.net/m3DDK/1/ so you can see how to get rid of your jQuery . (it's evil ;-)

2 things to note - your controller should look like this:

```
$scope.setSelected = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var valueNum = e.target.id.substr('btn'.length);
    $scope.selectOption = valueNum;
    $scope.$broadcast('myChange', valueNum);
};
```

and you html code like this:

```
        <div>
            <button ng-click="setSelected($event)" id="btn1">1</button>
            <button ng-click="setSelected($event)" id="btn2">2</button>
            <button ng-click="setSelected($event)" id="btn3">3</button>
        </div>
```

This can be even further cleaned up (if you will use ng-repeat) but I left that for you to handle.

Then in your directive, I've made an optional listener for the onChange event:

```
app.directive('selectableOption', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        scope.$on('myChange', function (event, valueNum) {
            //angular.element(element.children()[valueNum]).attr('selected', 'selected');
        });
    }
};
```

});

In conclusion - check out the fiddle, and get rid of your jQuery. You don't need it, Angular is just more powerful than that.
Plus a big tip - `element` inside a directive link is already a jQuery element.

Comment: Thank you for the help, the fiddle is just an example for my issue. My project is much larger than that and is very tightly coupled with a jQuery in-house plugin, so I cannot change too much of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because just changing the value of `select` will not update the `model`, the select directive listens to the `change` event and when that occurs updates the model.

In your case I would suggest you to trigger the `change` event inside the `myChange` handler in the directive.

```
app.directive('selectableOption', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            $(element).on('myChange', function () {
                element.trigger('change')
            });
        }
    };
});

$('button').on('click', function () {
    $('#mainSelect').val($(this).data('value'));
    $('#mainSelect').trigger('myChange');
});
```

To set the value of `select`, use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/juDfr/)